# Tend to be learning

Tags: grammar

What does "tend to be learning" mean in the following sentence? Why not "tend to learn"?

> It has been suggested that students of EFL tend to be leaning so that they can use English when travelling or to communicate with other people.

Comment: EFL... English Football League? Expo Freight Logistics? Energy Fiji Limited?

Comment: Prob. "English as a Foreign Language" (as opposed to advanced English grammar & other concepts for people who already are fluent in it.)

Comment: @RonJensen  It's "English as a Foreign Language", also often called ESL "English as a Second Language".

Comment: Babak, please do keep in mind that even native speakers of English sometimes can't write very well.  This is one example of that.  I also think "tend to learn" sounds much better.

Comment: @Andrew I have reached the maximum number of questions that I can ask. Please offer me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would think, since students are actively engaged in learning right now, it is more appropriate to say **"students tend to be learning English for reasons"** and save the other phrase for people who are not actively learning right now, **"people tend to learn English for reasons"**. The difference being who the noun is.

To put it another way, **to learn** is an infinitive verb, while **to be learning** is a more present tense phrase (while still probably technically infinitive).

Comment: Do you mean it resembles the difference between the two sentences "I like to learn English" and " I like learning English"?

Comment: @Andrew Do you agree with Ron Jensen's comment?

Comment: Could you please explain more Ron Jensen?

Comment: Could you please explain more?